# Bind clicks except when slider is already open

Tags: jquery, function, click

Before this question I recommend you go to the site and try adding something to the basket so you can see what it does.

If you go [here](http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/gracie.html) and add something to the basket, you'll see the slide-out tabs comes out to show your addition to the basket.

This is generated by binding the functions of the add basket button and the click of the .trigger (the handle for the slide out together) so that clicking 'add to basket' simulates a click to 'trigger'.

```
simpleCart.bind( "afterAdd" , function(){
    $('.trigger').click();
});
```

The problem occurs when you add a second item. Because the basket slide-out is already in it's 'out' state, the second time you hit 'add to basket' it calls the function again, which creates a "click" on the trigger, which this time CLOSES the basket slide-out.

How would I go about implementing a line of code that tests if the basket slide-out is in it's "out" state and then does not execute this function... or is there a better way?

The code that controls the slide-out is here:

```
    var settings = {
        objSlideTrigger: '.trigger',
        objSlidePanel: '.panel'
    }
```

Function for the slideout is: http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/js/slideout.js

Answer (score 1):

```
simpleCart.bind( "afterAdd" , function() {
    var isHidden = !$('.panel').is('.out');
    if(isHidden) {
        $('.trigger').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Get the following error on the page with this: Uncaught TypeError: Object false has no method 'click' wristwarmers.html:324
(anonymous function) wristwarmers.html:324
n.trigger simpleCart.min.js:28
b.extend.add simpleCart.min.js:6
b.bindInputs.callback simpleCart.min.js:42
f.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
h.handle.i

Comment: Sorry, had to make some changes. It should be okay now?

Comment: Still get lots of errors: "Uncaught ReferenceError: settings is not defined slideout.js:6" and "Uncaught TypeError: Object false has no method 'click' "

Comment: That's not caused by what I added o_O

Comment: Any ideas what is causing it? As it only turns up when I add this code.

Comment: I think it's because you're loading slideout.js before defining `settings`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19694/discussion-between-stephen-sarcsam-kamenar-and-francesca)

Answer (score 0):

In the function the slides out the div, check if it is hidden before sliding it out.

```
if ($(div:hidden).length > 0) {
    //slide out div
}
```

to add to current code add:

```
$('.trigger').is(':hidden').click();
```

Comment: I gave the same answer at first, then realized that it's not actually `:hidden`